# convert crt and key openvpn files to ovpn

Tags: openvpn

I've been sent some files to connect to an OpenVPN server at work.
I have done that before, but I had an .ovpn file and it was dead easy. Now it is confusing with the files (`ca.crt1`, `ta.key`, `clientHome.crt`, `clientHome.key`).

Is there a way to convert all of these files to a single .ovpn file?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you follow the Digital Ocean tutorial found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04). Start at Step 4 - Creating a Unified OpenVPN Profile for Client Devices.

A summary of the process -

1. Edit the .ovpn file to include your server's address
2. Paste the contents of the ca.crt, client1.crt, and client1.key files
   directly into the .ovpn profile
3. Make a few other small modifications as listed

Answer (score 1):

I created the following script ([link to the script's GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ofirule/8cb5765ca964cf751a0b2e2dc50a341e)) which works for my configuration:

```py
import sys, os

ALLOW_FILE_OPTIONS = ["ca", "cert", "dh", "extra-certs", "key", "pkcs12", "secret", "crl-verify", "http-proxy-user-pass", "tls-auth", "tls-crypt"]

filepath = sys.argv[1]

output_file = os.path.basename(filepath). replace(".conf", ".ovpn")

inline_tuples_to_add = []

with open(output_file, 'w') as dst:
    with open(filepath) as src:
        for l in src:
            option = l.split()
            if len(option) >= 2 and option[0] in ALLOW_FILE_OPTIONS and os.path.isfile(option[1]):
                inline_tuples_to_add.append((option[0], option[1]))
                continue

            dst.write(l)

    dst.write("key-direction 1\n\n") # needed fot tls-auth

    for t in inline_tuples_to_add : 
        tag_begining = "<{}>\n".format(t[0])
        dst.write(tag_begining)
        with open(t[1]) as tag_cpntent_file:
            dst.writelines(tag_cpntent_file.readlines())
        tag_ending = "</{}>\n\n".format(t[0])
        dst.write(tag_ending)
```

Running example:

```
python convert_openvpn_conf_file_to_ovpn_file.py /etc/openvpn/client.conf
```

This would create a .ovpn file on current working directory